# StringEnumConverter with Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 and some class have enums, and I'd like tha swagger API return enum as string.

Fox example:

```
namespace Model.Settings
{
    public enum SensorType
    {
        NONE = 0,
        IN = 1,
        OUT = 2
    }
}

......

namespace Model.Settings
{
    [JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public class SensorsSettings
    {
        [BsonElement("inOutDistance")]
        [Required]
        public int InOutDistance { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("type")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        [Required]
        public SensorType[] Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, when I call Http GET at API, I receive this JSON:

```
"sensorsSettings": {
      "inOutDistance": 65,
      "type": [
        1,
        2,
        0,
        0
      ]
    },
```

But I'd like:

```
"sensorsSettings": {
      "inOutDistance": 65,
      "type": [
        "IN",
        "OUT",
        "NONE",
        "NONE"
      ]
    },
```

Where I'm wrong?

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="5.5.1" />
```

Could you help me?

Comment: How are you configuring this in your startup?

Comment: Have you configured `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` in Startup?

Comment: When I put this one, I received this error:

**System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Model.Settings.SensorType[]' to type 'System.Enum'.**

Is there a converter to list of enum? Or I need create one?

Comment: It works now:

```
        [JsonProperty("type", ItemConverterType=typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        [Required]
        public SensorType[] Type { get; set; }
```

Tks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah as you mentioned in comments the answer is to change `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute to `[JsonProperty("type", ItemConverterType=typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute.

---

**You can also convert enums without these attributes.**

Just add this to your services:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```